# Как программно поставить точку останова на память?

Tags: c++, c, windows, x86

Возьмем цикл, который читает `bool` переменную

```
#include <cstdio>

volatile bool stop = false;

void loop() {
  while (!stop) {
    putchar('.');
  }
}
```

Мы хотим поменять значение `stop` на 4-м чтении, чтобы цикл напечатал <s>троеточие</s> многоточие и завершился.

Как на Windows перехватить чтения переменной stop, и поменять ее значение?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для точек останова на память можно использовать Guard Page. Это специальный флаг свойств страницы памяти, при котором обращение к странице вызывает исключение `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION (0x80000001)`. При этом флаг Guard Page сбрасывается, и повторное обращение к странице памяти исключений не вызывает.

Для чтений памяти, обработчик исключений может перехватить исключение `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION`, изменить значение памяти и пометить исключение обработанным. Чтение перезапустится, и прочитается новое значение выставленное в обработчике.

Чтобы точка останова не была одноразовой, флаг Guard Page надо выставить повторно. Для этого в обработчике `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` надо выставить флаг процессора TF (trap flag). Тогда перед выполнением следующей инструкции будет выброшено исключение `STATUS_SINGLE_STEP`. В его обработчике можно обновить флаг Guard Page, а также можно прочитать значение записанное предыдущей инструкцией, если она делала запись памяти.

В коде это выглядит следующим образом:

```
#include <windows.h>

int aux_counter = 0;  // счетчик для отсчета четырех чтений

// установка PAGE_GUARD для страницы в которую входит адрес |addr|
void set_guard_on_bool(volatile bool* addr) {
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
  VirtualQuery((void*)addr, &info, sizeof(info));
  DWORD unused;
  VirtualProtect((void*)addr, sizeof(*addr), info.Protect | PAGE_GUARD, &unused);
}

// обработчик исключений
LONG __stdcall exception_handler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* e) {
  switch (e->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode) {
    case STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION: {
      // параметры исключения - чтение/запись и адрес памяти
      bool is_read = e->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[0] == 0;
      void* location = (void*)e->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1];
      // проверяем что это чтение адреса |stop|
      // TODO: тут можно пропустить исключения для всех остальных страниц памяти 
      if (location == &stop && is_read) { 
        ++aux_counter;
        // завершаем цикл на 4-е чтение переменной
        if (aux_counter == 4) {
          stop = true;
          return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
        }
      }

      // выставляем TF чтобы вызвать исключение STATUS_SINGLE_STEP
      e->ContextRecord->EFlags |= 0x100;
      return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }
    case STATUS_SINGLE_STEP: {
      // обновляем флаг PAGE_GUARD
      set_guard_on_bool(&stop);
      return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }
    default: {
      // пропускаем остальные исключения
      return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  // устанавливаем обработчик исключений
  AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1 /* first */, exception_handler);
  // и выставляем флаг PAGE_GUARD
  set_guard_on_bool(&stop);

  loop();
}
```

Пример работы программы:

```
> g++ -O3 main.cpp && a.exe
...
```